# How could I center this, without messing up my pseudoelements?

Tags: html, css

[**Here's a fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/a5tjteet/6/) (code duplicated at bottom of this post)

The site is a vertical scroller made up of a number of these full-page `<section>`s, and I want to center the content on each panel, while leaving a heading fixed at the top and a link fixed at the bottom.

The problem is, as soon as I apply that translateX to the `<h1>` to center it, it messes up the stacking of the `.rbn` `:after` and `:before` pseudos.

(If you delete the first 9 lines of CSS you'll see what the ribbon should look like)

There's "fixes" to this problem, [**described here**](http://katydecorah.com/code/2014/01/01/z-index-and-transform/)

When I try anything along those lines though I:

- get horrible blurring on the text/outline if the browser width results in half-pixel problems, and
- I lose the smooth edges to the ribbon that the `scale(.999)` normally gives me.

This is in Chrome 35, I've not even started to look in other browsers yet.

**So I think centering the `h1` with `position:absolute;left:50%;transformX(-50%)` is a non-starter.  Even if it can be made to work, it's clearly an area that at least one of the major browsers is currently buggy/kludgy in, so I'd prefer to find an alternative solution.**

**What are my other options?**
:

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    text-align:center;
    padding:0;
    margin:0
}
section {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:table;
    background:#def;
    padding:120px 0 80px;
    position:relative
}
h1 {
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:50%;
    transform:translateX(-50%)
}
.content {
    background:#f2f2f2;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding:0 50px;
}
.downlink {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:10px;
    left:50%;
    transform:translateX(-50%)
}
/* ribbon styles */
 .rbn {
    position:absolute;
    background:#0f1111;
    color:#fff;
    padding:0.1em 1em;
    border:1px solid #888;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 0px 3px #0f1111;
}
.rbn::before, .rbn::after, .rbn>b::before, .rbn>b::after {
    content:'';
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-.35em;
    transform:scale(.999)
}
.rbn::before, .rbn::after {
    border:1em solid #0f1111;
    z-index:-2
}
.rbn::before {
    left:-1em;
    border-width:.9em 1.6em .9em 0.25em;
    border-left-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)
}
.rbn::after {
    right:-1em;
    border-width:.9em 0.25em .9em 1.6em;
    border-right-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)
}
.rbn>b::before, .rbn>b::after {
    border:1px solid;
    z-index:-1;
    border-color:#3d3d3d rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)
}
.rbn>b::before {
    left:0;
    border-width:.35em 0 0 .85em
}
.rbn>b::after {
    right:0;
    border-width:.35em .85em 0 0
}
```

Comment: That's not fixed anything regarding the heading as far as I can see in Chrome/Firefox - just made it wider...?

Comment: Have you got a screen shot of what you want it to look like as it looks fine in my chrome

Comment: I should point out that the background on the grey div isn't necessary, it was just to visualise things.

Comment: Do you only want one h1 and one footer on the page? If so I'd try putting them outside the sections altogether and using `position: fixed;` for them.

Comment: This is my best attempt so far.  The ribbons might look different for you here @Pete: http://jsfiddle.net/q69n0mkb/1/  

I don't like using extra markup if unnecessary though - I now have not one but TWO divs wrapping the content simply to vertically align it :(

Comment: Each section will have it's own h1 and footer unfortunately @gaynorvader

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/q69n0mkb/3/  (I added a couple of additional sections to make my intent more obvious - click on the "V" link)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend splitting your section in three. A header, middle and footer.

```
<style>
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0
    }

    h1, h2, p {
        margin: 0;
    }

    .header, .footer {
        width: 100%;
        height: 10%;
    }

    .content {
        width: 100%;
        height: 80%;
        display: table;
        background: #def;
        padding:0 ;
    }

    .inner {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>

<section>
    <div class="header">
        <h1>This is a heading</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="inner">
            <h1><b>This is a heading</b></h1>
            <h2>test</h2>
            <p>A mix of content in here.  h2, p, div, etc.</p>
            <div>
                <p>blah</p>
                <p>blah</p>
                <p>blah</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <p class="downlink"><a href="#nextsection">V</a></p>
    </div>
</section>
<section>
    <div class="header">
        <h1>This is a heading</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="inner">
            <h1><b>This is a heading</b></h1>
            <h2>test</h2>
            <p>A mix of content in here.  h2, p, div, etc.</p>
            <div>
                <p>blah</p>
                <p>blah</p>
                <p>blah</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <p class="downlink"><a href="#nextsection">V</a></p>
    </div>
</section>
```

That way you don't need to worry about positioning things absolutely. It also just makes things easier to centre text, etc.

Comment: This is essentially the solution I came to myself a few hours ago, albeit I didn't bother with wrappers for the header/footer, as they're consistently an h1 and a p so easily treated without wrappers.  I think it's a shame that all that extra markup (two divs) is needed just to center some content, but such is life.